# Testing a component that depends on 2 services

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a component that uses a service to retrieve information. But that service also gets configs from Configuration Service from a static variable conf. When running karma tests the const variable is undefined.

I am aware that I can create mock service, however shall I create 2 services to test this component? And if yes, I have other services that also use Configuration Service, so I have to create mock service for each of them? Seems like lots of work, but I haven't found a better solution :(
I provided both ConfigurationService and the Service I am using if that that makes any difference.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'apiUrl' of undefined`

apiUrl is a property of conf that is a static variable in ConfigurationService.

ConfigService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import * as YAML from 'js-yaml';
import {Config} from './models/Config';


@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  public static  conf: Config;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
   async load() {
       const res = await this.http.get<Config>('assets/config.yml', {responseType: 'text' as 'json'}).toPromise();
       ConfigService.conf = YAML.load(res).environment;
  }
}
```

InfoService.ts

```
export class InfoService {
  private InfoUrl = ConfigService.conf.apiUrl + '/info';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getInfo(){
    return http.get(InfoUrl);
  }
}
```

InfoComponent.ts

```
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  private info;
  constructor(private infoService: InfoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  loadInfo() {
    this.info = this.infoService.getInfo();
  }
```

InfoComponent.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { InfoComponent } from './info.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {InfoService} from './info.service';
import {ConfigService} from '../shared/config.service';


describe('InfoComponent', () => {
  let component: InfoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InfoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [InfoComponent],
      providers: [
          ConfigService
          InfoService,
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

   it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: _shall I create 2 services to test this component?_ No.  You should only mock direct dependencies of your component, not transitive ones.  Threat your service as an interface, and provide a _mock_ object that fulfills that interface. Any implementation details of that service arent relevant, thats the purpose of using a mock.

Comment: @Mathyn I've added code. I'm sure there is a simple and efficient way to test this, yet I am unable to find it. What do you think?

Comment: why don't you create a dependency over ConfigService  inside your InfoService 's constructor, the problem i see here is the static variable conf is accessed before it is set.

Comment: @PankajH do you mean i should put `InfoUrl = ConfigService.conf.apiUrl + '/info';` into Service constructor? Tried it. Same error

Comment: No, Create a dependency inside infoservice for ConfigService, your Infoservice's ctor should look like  constructor(private configservice:ConfigService, private http: HttpClient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your component needs `InfoService`. The core concept of Unit testing revolves around isolating the target code and test it. So, in your case, you dont need to create dependency on `ConfigService`. There should be a separate Unit test to test the behavior of `ConfigService`

```
class InfoServiceStub {
  getInfo(){
    return of({
        /// your mock data
     });
  }
}


describe('InfoComponent', () => {
  let component: InfoComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InfoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [InfoComponent],
      providers: [
          {provide: InfoService, useClass: InfoServiceStub },
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

   it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize that the purpose is to isolate the component. Did everything precisely as you describe, however, the problem remains the same. I don't understand why it keeps asking for apiUrl tho.